# Multiple plots with the same data in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I want to plot data (data1.txt) that has several columns but I want to use that data only once, so for example:

ApplePrice    Shop 1    Shop 2    Shop 3
Jan   10    9    8
Feb    10    10   9
Mar    9    10   10
Apr    8    9    9
May    10   10   10
...
...
etc

I know I can plot it with **plot 'data1.txt' using 1:2, plot 'data1.txt' using 1:3, plot 'data1.txt' using 1:4** and I will get 3 graphs that show the price difference between the shops, but then we have to use/process the data 3 times.

My question is: Can we use the data1.txt only once to get the 3 graphs? Something like plot 'data1.txt' using 1:2, using 1:3, using 1:4? (but that doesn't work)

Any ideas?

Thanks before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the special datafile `''`, which refers to the data just plotted.  For example,

```
plot 'data.dat' u 1:2, '' u 1:3, '' u 1:4
```

Comment: I'm not positive, but this very well could re-process the data each time, pulling out the information gnuplot actually needs, but that *usually* isn't a concern.

Comment: Yes, I'm also not sure about the subtlety of what gnuplot is doing with the data with each iteration of `''`.